# Как отобразить быстро меняющееся изображение в libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть ли какие то способы быстро отображать меняющееся на каждом кадре изображение в LibGDX не создавая на каждом кадре новый объект Texture, так как это занимает очень много времени?

Мне необходимо на каждом кадре рисовать новое изображение, но если переводить это изображение в Pixmap, из которого создавать Texture, то fps падает с 4000-5000 кадров до 40-60. При чем сам перевод картинки из BufferedImage в Pixmap не такой уж и долгий, а вот создания объекта Texture очень замедляет выполнение.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, по тому, что текстура загружается в GPU, а это не быстро. Как вариант - упакуйте изображения в одну текстуру и загрузите её сразу в GPU. Дальше уже оперируйте её частями (для удобства существует TextureAtlas)

Упаковать можно утилитой Texture Packer: https://libgdx.com/wiki/tools/texture-packer

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню стандарт openGL 3.0 он позволяет загрузить 8 текстур размера    2048*2048 (может и больше но уже будет зависеть от девайса), желательно их сразу подготовить в ECT2 формате (загрузка этого формата в 10 раз быстрее чем PNG) - он их загрузит очень быстро.
Соответственно все кадры надо уложить в эти 8 текстур и их переключение будет моментальным, просто меняешь координаты отображения и все.